# Azure Logic App, Delete old file only when a new one comes in

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am working on a logic app solution where I have to delete the older file only when the new one comes in. For e.g a file named "text 04/10/2023" should be deleted once "text 04/15/2023" comes in and till the new file comes in I want to re-load the same file "text 04/10/2023" into the database. I have everything set to load the file but unable to understand or figure out how to delete the files.

The logic reads a file from the blob loads it into the database, and it can remove the current file. But once the current file is removed it can no longer be re-processed till the new one comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use copy/delete blob actions to move the currently processed file between logical folders, to save it for subsequent runs, if needed.
Use Two Logical folders : <inbound_folder>, <done_folder>

At the end of processing, you could copy the *<inbound_folder>\04102023.txt* file to a different destination *<done_folder>\04102023.txt* within the container and then delete the *<inbound_folder>\04102023.txt* file.

At the start of processing, if *<inbound_folder>* is empty, then you could check the *<done_folder> for presence of any .txt file, and process it. Leave it in the *<done_folder> itself after processing.
If *<inbound_folder>* is not empty, then process the new file, empty the *<done_folder>* and then finally move(copy/delete blob) the new file to *<done_folder>*